# ASP .Net - MySql - Unable to read any data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mysql

I am stuck with a problem and do not have a single idea WTF is happening. I've got an C# web application that needs to communicate with a MySQL db using web services. I can use methods to insert data, but whenever I try to read anything (ExecuteReader or ExecuteScalar) it fails with this very strange message:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Now, the web service uses this class to communicate with the db:

```
 public class DatabaseHelper
{
    private MySqlCommand cmd;
    private MySqlConnection con;
    public DatabaseHelper()
    {
        String server = "localhost";
        String database = "testdb";
        String password = "password";
        String username = "root";


        String connString = "Server = " + server + "; Database = " + database + "; Uid = " + username + "; Pwd = " + password + "; default command timeout=60;";
        con = new MySqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connString;

        cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        cmd.Connection = con;
    }

    public void RunExecuteNonQuery(string sql, MySqlParameter[] param)
    {
        try
        {

            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            if (param != null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            }
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            con.Close();

        }
    }
    public object RunExecuteScalar(string sql, MySqlParameter[] param)
    {
        if (param != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        object ret;
        con.Open();
        ret = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        return ret;
    }

    public MySqlDataReader RunExecuteDataReader(string sql, MySqlParameter[] param)
    {
        if (param != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        MySqlDataReader ret = null;

        con.Open();

       ret = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
       cmd.Parameters.Clear();


        return ret;
    }
}
```

It fails on cmd.ExecuteReader or cmd.ExecuteScalar!

On the other hand, a method from the web service looks as following:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public string[] GetCategories()
    {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
        DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper();
        MySqlDataReader dr = dh.RunExecuteDataReader(sql, null);
        List<String> categories = new List<string>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            categories.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();

        return categories.ToArray();
    }
```

It is really strange since the error is very cryptic (I am not using a dictionary at all) and I have used this same class in many other applications. I tried this same solution on a different computer with the same result. I have even tried different versions of MySql.Data.dll

The error stack:

> > System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException was unhandled by user code   HResult=-2146232969   Message=The given key was not
> >     present in the dictionary.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
> >            at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
> >            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetChararcterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName)
> >            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData41()
> >            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetFieldMetaData()
> >            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnMetadata(Int32 count)
> >            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
> >            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> >     behavior)
> >            at Panopticon.DataLayer.DatabaseHelper.RunExecuteDataReader(String sql,
> >     MySqlParameter[] param) in C:\Users\Visar\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2010\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\DataLayer\DatabaseHelper.cs:line 84
> >            at Panopticon._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Visar\Documents\Visual Studio
> >     2010\Projects\TestApp\TestApp\Default.aspx.cs:line 16
> >            at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
> >     EventArgs e)
> >            at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
> >            at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
> >            at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> >     InnerException:

Comment: would refactor your helper as well to read from a .config file and get away from hardcoded values..

Comment: Could you post the error stack plz

Comment: I was reading from web.config of course thinking that there was the problem :(

Comment: if you get values back from reading the config it's usually a good sign.. 9 times out of 10 the issues is with the Parameters as well as the Parameter type as well as the SQL Statement but since you're doing Select * I don't think it's the command..

Comment: @Mark - Just added the error stack.

Comment: Try @Aghilas example it's looking good at the moment and should help you in regards to getting your code corrected

Comment: Hmmm. Since last call was to .GetChararcterSet before heading into the dictionary, I woud guess either the DBVersion was not found or the CharSetName was not found. Might it me a locale issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace with this code - you can delete `AddRange` method

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

And add foreach treatment

```
 foreach (var p in param)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        }
```

Best Practise as mentionned with DJ KRAZE, is to use `AddWithValue method`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx

Comment: or cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues(param) the .Add method has been depricated btw

Comment: yes i know but first time is to find problem , and second time to answer with AddWithValue, Thank you DJ KRAZE  for remark , i add your answer to my answer

Comment: not a problem Aghilas your answer is good enough +1 I gave you the other problem I noticed is he's passing Params as an Array.. which could also cause him potential problems if one of the params is not filled or is null but your solution should be enough to get him going

Comment: That is not the issue here though. I do not pass any parameters. The same error occurs even if I change the method to not include parameters at all.

Comment: I did try your suggestion though... still the same issue :(